# how to ensure that values of a column in database table is shown as columns of datagridview

Tags: c#

Hey Guys I was trying to develop accounting application thanks to windows forms appication C# and what I want to achive is that I have a column in a database table called CategoryName and it has values as Transport, Food and Internet and the question is how it is possible to put those values as columns in datagridview and if I add new values in CategoryName, then they have to be added as datagridview columns automatically.

Comment: what output you expect please provide example

Comment: you'd have to query the database and get the list of names, then manually bind the datagridview to create columns, one for each name in your list. What have you researched so far into datagridviews?

Comment: @CoolJK, so the output that I expect is the values or, say, records in CategoryName column are shown as columns in datagridview and if I do crud operations on CategoryName records then it has to affect columns in datagridview, for example, if I add new CategoryName, say, Mobile Network then that record or value of CategoryName has to be shown as column of datagridview

Comment: @ADyson, but I want to ensure that category names are not hardcoded in datagridview, that is, if I delete a specific record of CategoryName then that deleted category should not be displayed as column in datagridview

Comment: " I want to ensure that category names are not hardcoded", they won't be. Research data binding. Your code can bind them dynamically based on the content of the database each time it runs the query. Note though that the gridview won't be automatically notified if you add or delete records from the table, you need to set a timer to refresh it regularly and re-bind